# How to write LINQ Query in instance table for many to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am beginner in LINQ and Enitty Framework and I am stuck at one place. I have many to many relationship between "Referral" and "Referrer" table. I have named it as "ReferralInstance" table.

Referral Model

```
 public class Referral
    {
        public Referral()
        {
            ReferralInstances = new Collection<ReferralInstance>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int ReferralId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ReferralInstance> ReferralInstances { get; set; }
    }
```

Referrer Model:

```
Public class ApplicationUser
  {
       public ApplicationUser()
       {
            ReferralInstances = new Collection<ReferralInstance>();
       }
       [Key]
       public string ReferrerId {get;set;}
       public ICollection<ReferralInstance> ReferralInstances { get; set; }
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
  }
```

Instance Table

```
public class ReferralInstance
{
    [Key]
    public int ReferralInstanceId { get; set; }
    public bool ReferralStatus { get; set; }

    public int ReferralId { get; set; }
    public virtual Referral Referral { get; set; }

    public string ReferrerId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Referrer { get; set; }
}
```

**Fluent API:**

```
 dBModelBuilder.Entity<Referral>()
                  .HasMany(r => r.ReferralInstances)
                  .WithRequired(r => r.Referral)
                  .HasForeignKey(r => r.ReferralId);

  dBModelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                 .HasMany(r => r.ReferralInstances)
                 .WithRequired(r => r.Referrer)
                 .HasForeignKey(r => r.ReferrerId).
                 WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Now from UI I will get an input ReferrerId as Let's say ABC. I want to get list of ReferralInstances which has FK as ABC, and then I want to get all the corresponding list of referrals for that.

My novice attempt below:

```
public ActionResult ReferredCandidates()
        {
            var referrerId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            // trying to get list of "ReferralInstance"
            var referralInstanceList = _context.ReferralInstances.Where(r => (r.ReferrerId == referrerId)).Select(r => r.ReferralId);
            // Now I want to get all the referrals that match that id list I got above
            // what to do here
            // var referralss = _context.Referrals.Where(r => (r.ReferrerId  r.ReferralInstances.);

            return View(referrals);
        }
```

EXAMPLE:

Referral Table

---

```
ReferralId       Text
1                HelloWorld
2                FooBar
3                HelloFoo
```

ReferralInstance Table:

---

```
 PK     ReferralId       ReferrerId

  1         1              ABC   
  2         1              DEF
  3         1              XYZ
  4         2              ABC
  5         3              DEF
```

Referrer Table

---

```
    ReferrerId           Flag
    ABC                   USA   
    XYZ                   INDIA
    DEF                   UK
```

Now suppose I get entry as ABC, then I want below result

```
Result Set

ReferralId         Text
1                 HelloWorld
2                  FooBar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly query the navigation property `ReferralInstance.Referral`:

```
var referrals = _context.ReferralInstances
    .Where(r => r.ReferrerId == referrerId)
    .Select(r => r.Referral);
```

Maybe you want to add `Distinct()` to the query.

Comment: This looks efficient too. :) Thanks sir.. :)